# Which of the following does not interrupt a running process?

Tags: process

Which of the following does not interrupt a running process?

```
A   A device
B   Timer
C   Scheduler
D   Power failure
```

The answer is D, but I am unable to understand how the running process will not be interrupted in the event of power failure.

Comment: A quick Google search for this exact question yields conflicting answers - some say C while others say D. Strange, considering that the question and its choices are identical in all the search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See first by looking at the options it is clear that (A),(B)and (C) will or can interrupt a running process.

A: device by generating interrupt.

B: Timer is an anther implementation.A mechanism is needed whereby activities can be scheduled to run at some relatively precise time. Any microprocessor that wishes to support an operating system must have programmable interval timer which periodically interrupts the processor.

and

C:Scheduler is clear and obvious.
now coming to

D: in case of a power failure the whole system will shut down, nothing will run. While interrupting means that "stopping some process and running some other procedure." while as power failure will stop everything not interrupt a process. Hope you got it :)

Answer (score 4):

(D) is not correct answer. 
(C) Schedular Process is the correct answer. 
The reason being, A schedular process only schedules or we can say selects a process from ready queue to be run on CPU. So no interrupt is generated in that case.
When there is power failure, surely an interrupt "power-off signal" will be generated.
For your references :

http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/interrupts/inthandlers1.html

http://www.cs.iit.edu/~virgil/cs470/Book/chapter6.pdf

Answer (score 3):

(C)   ---->  Correct

In the book operating systems by Galvin it states **the module that gives control of CPU to the process selected by the Short-term scheduler is Dispatcher**, it takes care of context switch and allows the new process to run. To summarise the Dispatcher causes an interrupt, the process scheduler does not.

(D) is wrong a power failure causes the whole system to halt abruptly.

Answer (score 0):

Read about interrupts [here (wiki page)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt)

 Answer D is correct, because no interrupt will be sent to the process in case of power failure, and will be sent in all other cases.